# SVN - Multiple branches for project

Tags: svn

I have one core site which has all the core functions.

I then need to create 4 sub projects which will use the same core site but will have different front ends.

From guides I think I could use branches but I couldn't work out if a bug is found in the core site would it be possible to commit changes to the core and then update the branches ?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Thanks everyone! I will have a go at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike other advices here I would recommend you to stick to the tool you are used to. Switching to git requires some solid background in SCM. It is more powerful, but also has a higher learning curve.

I would rather advice you to use an extra branch for the core that is pulled into the branches that use them means `svn:externals`.

For help have a look at the [documentation here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html). This way you'll save yourself the tedious work of synchronizing the core for each branch. Even if you need one of your branch to stick to a specific revision of the core you can do it. The link does not even need to be in the same physical repository, what makes it a really flexible tool.

But make sure you use the 1.6 version for the client and server. I experienced some trouble with other versions as the format for the links appears to have been modified and extended.

Comment: This is an option too... But you can't specify the version you need to work with your repo. Git submodules are "pointers" to a specific commit inside the submodule repo.

Comment: You can with SVN too: You specify the revision you want to stick to in the external property using the `@` notation.

Comment: I must say this is relatively recent (about 3 years old). If you switched to git by that time, I would be the last guy to take you back to svn :-) git has more features and is definitively more powerful. But sometimes you are not so flexible to choose the tool and he asked for a svn solution... Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest use a distributed version control system like `git` or `mercurial`. Although branching in SVN is `O(1)`, merging isn't. In fact if the core is going to be the same you may as well make it a library and import it rather.

Answer (score 1):

A branch should only be used if you are developing in one library. You would end up merging or pickaxeing changes for all repos - this is a nightmare!

I would suggest git too... svn has no submodules.

You can do something like this:

MainLibraryRepo: Your shared Code

Repo1: Site1

- submodule: MainLibraryRepo
- additional submodules ...

Repo2: Site2

- submodule: MainLibraryRepo
- additional submodules ...

Reasons for this setup:

- you can bind a Site to a defined version of your library (updates of your library can be tested before commiting the main Repo)
- the code that can be treated as a single unit should remain in it's own repo an have it's own history

Reasons for git:

- it's fast
- merging is easy and fast
- submodules is the solution you need here
- you can develop without server/client

Comment: Svn has svn:externals, what are the advantages of submodules over those?

Comment: Submodules point directly to a commit/tag of another repo. You will get exactly the same code when you clone it.